# How to open and edit an XML file from res/xml local project folder

Tags: android, xml, file

I can open the xml files from my local folder of an android project in Eclipse to read the values:

```
Resources res = activity.getResources();
XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.tittes);
```

But how could I open a local xml file to edit the file and save it after?

---

Thanks for the replies!.,

I mean with a local file, a XML file I need to read and edit for data storage purposes. I've decided to place the file in the **asset folder** and I can open it easily for read::

```
*DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputStream iS = this.getAssets().open("myFile.xml");  
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(iS);*
```

...,, but I don`t obtain, after many attemps, **the way to save the file to edit**: My last attempt is:

```
                        *TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();

                //create string from xml tree
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                trans.transform(source, result);
                String xmlString = sw.toString();


                OutputStream f0;
            byte buf[] = xmlString.getBytes();
            **f0 = new FileOutputStream("/assets/wines.xml");**
            //f0 = new FileOutputStream("file:///assets/wines.xml");
            for(int i=0;i<buf .length;i++) {
               f0.write(buf[i]);
            }
            f0.close();
            buf = null;*
```

and the failed result is **File not found!!**!,. I come from C# projects,.and I couldn`t imagine that save a modified file was so dificult,.,

any ideas?!¿!?   thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

> but anyone know how could I open a local xml file to edit the file and save it after.

If by "local xml file" you mean a file in `getFilesDir()`, use DOM, or SAX, or the `XmlPullParser`.

If by "local xml file" you mean a resource, and you want to modify that resource, that is not possible at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to edit xml resources in the res folder in your program.
You can try another way, such as saving your resources to SharedPreference or SQLite at the first time your app starts, and later on you just edit and use your own copy.
This is useful when you use the resource to fill some component, but not good for layouts.